# Access to Java model List from Javascript/JQuery dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have a model as `List<Collaborateur>` coming from my Controller Action to my JSP. And I have the following function in JQuery/Javascript:

```js
function showCollaborateurEmail(index) {
  alert("${collaborateurs[1].email}"); // Works
  alert("${collaborateurs[2].email}"); // Works
  //....
  alert("${collaborateurs[index].email}"); // Not working
}
```

So I want to show the email of my `Collaborateur` model dynamically by calling the function `showCollaborateurEmail(index)`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what isindex value ??

Comment: not possible: index is a javascript variable and it is not available on the server side.

Comment: index value is a numeric value (may be 1,2 ,... )

Comment: This is the common error when someone start using JSP. You can't mixed Client Side Langage (Javascript) with Server Side Langage (JSP, JSTL). The JSTL tags will be parsed on the server then the resulting file will be send via the HTTPRequest. From there, it will reach the client where the Javascript will be executed (with the HTML)

Comment: Yes but as you can see the instruction `alert("${collaborateurs[1].email}");` works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you face is the exchange of data between code on server side and code on client side. There are multiple ways to achieve your goal. You can...

1. store the list-elements in a hidden form-field (escaping of delimiter might be a challenge) or
2. generate javascript - code on server side in JSP that creates a javascript array with the list-elements or
3. use ajax.

1 and 2 are rather ad hoc - solutions for a small problem. 3 is rather a bigger solution (depending on your technical environment) which additionally provides the possibility to avoid page reloads.

Comment: 2 and 3 will result in the same logic, the need to parse the values into a common langage, JSON (not native), XML(heavy), ... but this is always the best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to explore:
1) generate a javascript array with all the elements of the list, and access the at will on the client side (javascript)
2) access the "collaborateurs" via an ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to mix server and client code like this through jsp. 
Instead you should create a servlet and call what you need with ajax.

If you want to use a dirty/quick trick I think you can build back the array from the server side to the client side inside a `<script>` tag

For example:

```
<script> 
var emailArray = [
    <%for (int i = 0; i > collaborateurs.length; i++){ %>
    "<%=collaborateurs[i].email %>"
    <%
        if(i < collaborateurs.length - 1){
            %>, <%
        }
    }%>
];
</script>
```

(I wrote this by hand so I'm not sure the syntax is correct, but I hope you got the idea)

Comment: That's dirty ! You could at least use a JSTL foreach loop ;) EDIT : You probably need to had quotes

Comment: you are absolutely right, but years passed since I used jsp, in fact I said it was a dirty solution myself ahah. For everyone seeing this answer: the code is only to explain the means, not optimal at all.

Answer (score 0):

One more option you will have is converting your List object to json and then set it to a variable in jsp while compiling phase and the on client side parse json and make an object and iterate over it. This way you can access your list even after loading your page also.

You can use API like gson,Jackson etc.

Example :-

```
List<Object> list1=new ArrayList<>();
// Add values to list here
JSONArray obj=new JSONArray(list1);
```

In `JSP` :

```
var collaborateursList=${collaborateurs};

function showCollaborateurEmail(index) {
  alert(collaborateursList[1].email);
  alert(collaborateursList[2].email); 
  alert("collaborateursList[index].email);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please verify the `index` is passing correctly to the function and try using this

```
alert("${collaborateurs[" + index + "].email}");
```

Comment: You have to distinguish what happens on server side and what on client side. The server side generates the page including the javascript code and sends it to the client. index is a javascript variable. It is only any string from the point of view of the server and an unknown token if you try to use it as server - side - variable. There is nothing that automagically reevaluates server side expressions after the page is loaded.