# Accessing a javascript element in server side JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have a script tag in a JSP and in that, I am reading a server side variable which I have read from the session. 
I need to use a javascript variable (`campaignIndex`) in that server side variable ( `getCreditAmountMax`) like so:

```
<script>
    var campaignIndex = jq111("select#campaigns").find(':selected').index();
    GT.utilities.updateData(creditAmountDiv, "maxAmount", '<%=creditCampaignsModel.getCreditCampaigns().get(campaignIndex).getCreditAmountMax()%>', false);

</script>
```

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to dynamically generate Javascript code in JSP. It is not possible that JSP-expressions get reevaluated at client. From the point of view of the Javascript code it's only a constant.

Similar question: [Access to Java model List from Javascript/JQuery dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40237058).